# How to link with the command ld

Tags: c++, ld

i got 2 files: "test.o" and "testlib.a" both files are in the same folder

now i want to join them with the linker. The Problem is have to link them with the "ld" command!

So can some tell me how the syntax is?

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
ld -I -o testprog test.o testlib.a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let g++ take care of all the details for you - it will call `ld` with all the correct arguments:

```
g++ -o testprog test.o testlib.a
```

If you want to see the command that is being passed to `ld` so that you can invoke it directly then just add the `-v` flag:

```
g++ -v -o testprog test.o testlib.a
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have given will work *if* your program doesn't need the C++ runtime library parts that most program uses. You will need to provide the C++ startup code and the standard C++ library if you want to make use of any of the C++ runtime functionality (e.g. your code starts in `main` and have `stdin`, `cin`, `atexit`'s table and many other similar things initialized).

There is little reason to use `ld` directly. Like Paul R says, use `g++` to do the linking. It knows how to do all the things you need. Only time you don't want to do that is if your are building an operating system (or kernel module) or some other components that don't use the normal standard runtime library bits.